# how this else is getting excuted

Tags: c, if-statement

I am confused with the executing of both if and else

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    if(!(printf("hello")))
    {

    }
    else
    {
        printf("World");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output: helloworld

Comment: The value of the expression `printf("hello")` is the number of characters written, in your case it's `5`. `5` is "true"; `!5` is "false" ... so the `else` runs

Comment: [This `printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) might be helpful. Pay close attention to what it [*returns*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf#Return_value).

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to add some important details. What output did you expect instead. Why would you expect the `else` not to be executed?

Comment: The empty "if" block is not executed. Only the test and else block are executed.

Answer (score 1):

when the CPU reaches if statement, printf() function is called and the return value of printf function is evaluated for Boolean true or false condition.Since printf return the count of input it is outputting on the screen. For “Hello” it will be “5”. Which will be always considered as Boolean TRUE by if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
if(!(printf("hello"))) { /* !5, i.e. 0 so the if fails - but it does print hello */
   /* some code... it doesn't execute this */
}
else { 
    printf("World"); /* prints world */
}
```

At `!(printf("hello")`, `printf()` first prints `hello` and then *returns the number of printed characters, which is `5`*. Then `!5` becomes `0`, and it makes the `if` condition false, so the `else` gets executed, which prints `World`.

To know what `printf()` will return, read the manual page of [printf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> **Return value**
>
> Upon successful return, these functions *return the number of
>   characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to
>   strings)*.

Also,

> I am confused with the executing of both if and else ?

**No**, the `if` block doesn't execute, only the `else` does; since `printf()` is inside the condition part of the `if` block, printing `hello` doesn't mean it entered the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

The program runs the if statement, which is `printf("hello")` (prints the output to the console). Checks if it is true, in your case `printf` return `5` and it is `true`, `!true` is `false`. at the end it is something like this.

```
if(false) { ... } else { printf() }
```

That is why you get `helloworld` in console

Comment: This is not worded well. `printf("hello")` is not a statement. It is an expression. (If it were by itself and followed by a semicolon, that could form an expression statement. But, inside the `if` statement, it is not a statement.) It is better to say the program evaluates the controlling expression of the `if` statement.